# How to manage bmp to jpeg conversion if the image sides are not divisible by 8?

Tags: image-processing, jpeg, bmp

While converting a bmp to a jpeg we take DCT of discrete units of 8 X 8 of the image. Suppose we have an image where the height and width is not divisible by 8, then we will have some pixels left on the sides of the image.

How do we manage that ?

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the answer is zero padding. Zero pad the image such that its width and height become divisible by 8 apply DCT and then remove the padding